# Cambio de map() de python 2.7 a 3.x en código

Tags: python, map

Estoy tratando de actualizar el código realizado para Python 2.7 del algoritmo A priori para recorrer
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/cse40647/cse40647/blob/sp.14/10%20-%20Apriori.ipynb
Cuando ejecuto:

```
import a priori #El código está en el enlace
dataset =  [['Bread', 'Milk'], 
        ['Bread', 'Diapers', 'Beer', 'Eggs'], 
        ['Milk', 'Diapers', 'Beer', 'Coke'], 
        ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Diapers', 'Beer'], 
        ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Diapers', 'Coke'],
        ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Diapers'],
        ['Bread', 'Coke']]
F, soporte = apriori.apriori(dataset, min_support=0.4, verbose=True) 
# En este paso se produce el error y aunque cambie a map, requiere más 
#mbios

# Generamos las reglas de asociación de la lista de itemsets frecuentes
# En este caso, se filtran las que no llegan a una confianza determinada.
H = apriori.generate_rules(F, soporte, min_confidence=0.9, verbose=True)
```

Da un error porque ahora no es lista sino map(), y no logra establecer la lista de ítems a recorrer porque se queda con los índices. ¿Cuál es la forma más fácil de actualizar el código sin tener que cambiar a otro tipo de estructuras?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

La forma más facil ahora es convertir a una lista los objetos map que te devuelve python3 cuando usas `map`.

### Editar `create_candidates()`.

```
def create_candidates(dataset, verbose=False):
    # logica del método sin cambios

    # Map c1 to a frozenset because it will be the key of a dictionary.

    # crea una lista para enumerar el map object
    return list(map(frozenset, c1))
```

### Editar `apriori()`

```
def apriori(dataset, min_support=0.5, verbose=False):
    # docstring sin cambios.

    C1 = create_candidates(dataset)

    # crea una lista para enumerar el map object.
    D = list(map(set, dataset))
```

Con esos dos cambios debes empezar a ver resultados.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Perfecto. Rápida respuesta y en seguida funcionó. Muchas gracias